# Bounds of a remainder of $\ln(1+x)$ Taylor polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Question: Prove that if $-1 < x \leq 0$, then the remainder term $R_{n,0}$ of degree $n$ at $0$ for $\ln(1+x)$ satisfies: $$|R_{n,0}| \leq \frac {|x|^{n+1}} {(1+x)(n+1)}$$
My attempts: Since $$f^{(n+1)}(t)=\frac {(-1)^nn!} {(1+t)^{n+1}},$$

in the Lagrange form of the remainder I get $$\left|\frac {f^{(n+1)}(t)} {(n+1)!}x^{n+1}\right|=\frac {|x|^{n+1}} {(n+1)(1+t)^{n+1}}\leq\frac {|x|^{n+1}} {(n+1)(1+x)^{n+1}}.$$
But here i get stuck, since $(1+x)^{n+1}\leq(1+x)$. I tried the integral form: $$\left|\int_0^x \frac {f^{(n+1)}(t)} {n!}(x-t)^ndt\right|=\int_x^0 \frac {|x-t|^n} {(1+t)^{n+1}}dt \leq \int_x^0 \frac {|x-t|^n} {(1+x)^{n+1}}dt$$
and the same problem occures. I would love some help here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$HINT$

In the integral form make the change of variables: $$u=\frac{x-t}{1+t}$$

Comment: Well, that's about all I needed :). For some reason the answer book says that the integral form is $\int_0^x \frac {t^n} {1+t} dt$ without showing any intermediary steps, it just starts from that expression. I'm not sure if that's a mistake or if the author just skipped a bunch of steps but it really confused me. Regardless, thanks for the hint!